# How to implement lazy load for images returned from a server in ES5?

Tags: javascript, html, image, dynamic, lazy-loading

On one page, I'm trying to lazy load potentially hundreds of images that are returned from my server as blobs. I've tried converting them to base64 data uris then using some lazy loading techniques, but understandably that didn't work, since the data uri is already in the html, which means the browser still needs to load the image data even if it's not going to display it right away.

Is there some way to lazy load dynamic images returned by a server as blobs? Or some way to convert them to use remote image urls then use typical lazy loading that way?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you have received them already, you do not have to load them again. Please add a [mcve] to get more help.

Comment: @KoshVery it's a question about the general way to do something. An example would be far too complex to be of any use, and would escape the entire purpose of the question.

Comment: I believe the example would illustrate the issue better than words.

Comment: I agree no example is needed, the description is pretty clear.

Answer (score 3):

## ES5 approach : XMLHttpRequest

In this scenario you get an `arraybuffer` from the ajax request, that must be converted into a `base64` string, before being useful. (IE10+ Compatible Method)

```js
let myImg = document.getElementById('myImg');
let url = "https://placekitten.com/200/300";

let request  = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open ("GET", url, true);
request.responseType  = "arraybuffer";
request.send (null);

request.onreadystatechange= function(response){
  if (request.readyState === 4) {
    if (request.status === 200) {
      // convert received arrayBuffer into base64 encoded string
      var imgBase64 = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(request.response)));
      // assign base64 encoded image to image source
      myImg.src=  'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imgBase64;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" />
```

> Note: CORS must be taken in consideration, when retrieving images from external domains.

---

## ES6 approach : Fetch

You can use `fetch` to retrieve your images, and inject them in the DOM as soon as you receive them...

```js
let myImage = document.getElementById('myImg');
let url = "https://placekitten.com/200/300";

fetch(url)
.then( response=> {
  // if response is OK, covert it into a blob
  if(response.ok) return response.blob();
  else throw new Error('Response not OK');
})
.then(myBlob=>{  
  // Assign it to the image src using createObjectURL
  myImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
})
.catch(function(error){
  // hadle errors
  console.log(error.message);
});
```

```html
<img id="myImg" />
```

You can get more details about [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and [createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) in the Mozilla Developer webpage.

---

Previous code can be easily converted into reusable functions, suitable for generic scenarios.

Comment: Thanks. While this might put me on the right track, is it possible to do with ajax instead? I need to support IE11, and would prefer not to use a polyfill for fetch. I've never used fetch, but it looks pretty similar to ajax

Comment: Sorry for not quite understanding your solution yet, what exactly is the lazy loading portion of this answer? If I return a list of hundreds of images from my server in the one response, your answer won't really help, correct? Where exactly is the lazy loading implemented? Thanks for the help

Comment: This code lets you load the images, only when you need them, but you have to load each image one by one, and inject them in the DOM manually. If you recieve a list of Image Urls from your server, you have to iterate that list, and execute this code for each element.

Comment: "This code lets you load the images, only when you need them" - That's what I'm confused about, how does your ES5 code snippet know when we need the images? Where exactly is this functionality?

Comment: i would wrap that code inside a function, accepting 2 arguments : imgUrl and targetImageElementId... and call that function when you need to load more images

Comment: I guess that's where the confusion lies, I was not clear. I want to display all of the images returned, in a gallery, but to avoid the browser crashing and such, only load images as the user scrolls down. I can figure out that last part, I'm just having some trouble with the idea of having all of the images ready to load. I guess instead I could load like 40 images at a time then load more as the user scrolls down? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: There are some implementations that load the images automatically as soon as the scroll reaches them , other implementations that also unload the ones that have been already scrolled... Take a look at this: https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/

Comment: I'm aware of these types of solutions and have implemented them before, the problem I'm having is they don't work with base64 data uri's, which was pretty much the point of this question, to try to figure out how the get one of these solutions to work with base64 data uri's, or convert blobs from the server to remote image urls or something